# Maslow's Hierarchy of Needs

Tags: psychology, psychoanalysis

Before I self-actualize can I help people self-actualize, because that usually happens after a person self actualizes?

Comment: Further down the hierarchy are belonging and esteem needs often most easily met through helping others.  So clearly those others (stuck at a lower level of need, at least temporarily) are helping the person ministering to them to become self-actualized.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you may help someone self-actualize, even though you are not "fully" self-actualized. Further more, you may even do it without you being aware you are doing it.

Comment: This answer is a little thin. Could you elaborate or add references?